# Is it possible to use a while loop and to append the results into a linked list?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to use a while loop and to append the results into a linked list?

This is what I've attempted though It isn't able to be called.
Does the matter of it looping through a list made from an object have any effect on this?

```
      LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
      return list;

  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      Data data = new Data(0, null, 0);
      sales_agents sales = new sales_agents();
      seller_thread one = new seller_thread();
      while (true) {
          ArrayList<Data> books = new ArrayList<Data>();
          System.out.println(sales.getSales_1() + "Has been added to catalogue");
          books.add(new Data(1, (String) sales.getSales_1(), sales.getValue()));
          one.list().add(String.valueOf(books));}`
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(books)` - what are you expecting this to return?

Comment: `ArrayList<Data> books = new ArrayList<Data>();` - this is done for every iteration of the loop, so it will only ever have one element in it - kinda useless I think.

Comment: thx didn't notice lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a while loop and to append the results into a linked list?

Yes, it is.

What you need to do is to set the condition of exiting the loop, and also your list should be declared in outer scope.

*And one note: to get the string, containing the information about the object, **`Object.toString()`** is usually used.*

```
sales_agents sales = new sales_agents();
seller_thread one = new seller_thread();

ArrayList<Data> books = new ArrayList<>();
int maxSize = 10; // As an example
while (books.size < maxSize) {
    System.out.println(sales.getSales_1() + " has been added to catalogue");
    final Data item = new Data(1, (String) sales.getSales_1(), sales.getValue()); 
    books.add(item);
    one.list().add(item.toString()); // Override your toString() method in Data class to return the string you want 
                                     // (all information you need to know about the object)
}
```

But why cannot you just do this, because you do not really use `ArrayList`

```
while (one.list().size() < maxSize) {
    System.out.println(sales.getSales_1() + " has been added to catalogue");
    final Data item = new Data(1, (String) sales.getSales_1(), sales.getValue()); 
    one.list().add(item.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!f Great explanation.

Comment: @coedr I am glad it helps. If it was useful for you and your question is closed, you can accept my answer :)

Comment: @Steyrix very well explained !

Comment: @MandarDharurkar thank you :) It is a very pleasant comment for me